# Should I lower my character's level to join a new campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e

A friend of mine wants to start a new 5e game but will reset all involved to level 3. This makes me very unhappy, as I worked hard to get my paladin to where he is. Granted he is very overpowered. Should I give up XP, or just look for a different high-Level game?

I understand that it may seem I'm being unreasonable, but I've yet to encounter a big challenge at my current level, and I would like something challenging that does not involve being at lower levels. Gameplay with a wide range of abilities is intriguing to me.

Sidenote - my paladin is level 15

Comment: How much fun do you expect to have when your character is level 15 and everyone else's character is level 3?

Comment: True enough, however, my initial thinking was for everyone to keep their level and gear from prior games, as I'm looking for a challenge at higher levels

Comment: Its a a legitimate question, but it does raise a few issues - what if you made some changes so it was less about you and more about the general underlying problem - should I de-level a high level character to join a level 3 campaign?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this question, though based in a legitimate concern, isn't primarily opinion based. The problem being that nobody can really make this decision for you. Only you can decide if you would find a character reset fun. As a side note, cursing in a question isn't [very nice](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: @Adam Thank you for your comment, i was just curious how others perceived my thinking, and how they would act if also in such situation

Comment: @ObliviousSage Well, isn't the idea of bounded accuracy that that can work?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Accuracy might be bounded but damage and healing aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the other respondants that you should not be allowed to join a table of level 3s with a level 15 character. Keep your folder, your character may later join the story when everyone reaches level 15...

If you really like the paladin class, play a new one.

If you want your old character to be part of the campaign, ask your GM if he can be used as an NPC. Perhaps he serves as a patron for the PCs, perhaps he is a mover and shaker in the kingdom.

About your new one, perhaps he is a disciple of the former, perhaps he's a descendant, perhaps he's someone who is looking for relics of the former. There are ways to include your old character in your new character.

But a straight-up port should not happen, and I support your GM here.

Answer (score 8):

Why not create a new character? This DM wants to run a L3 campaign at present, but other games will come along in time. However, your odds of getting into them will not be improved if you make a scene now.

Comment: You do have a point, I was under the impression that my entire character would be perma-reset. But would it be acceptable to simply recreate my character for this L3 campaign?

Comment: @Angrypaladin You should discuss that with your DM in person, or via email, phone, etc.  It's between you and the DM how to address that kind of reset.  (John's "why not create a new character" is the only valid answer I could come up with for your question, so I have little else to offer you).

Comment: The way the OP is wording some things makes me wonder if he somehow thinks he is only allowed to have and play one character at a time ever. New game, new character - don't expect them to be portable unless it is specifically part if the format, like Adventurer's League.